# Contar quantidade de pessoas da uma tabela separando por faixa de idade, sexo e empresa

Tags: mysql

Estou com dificuldades em fazer funcionar um `select` aonde tem que trazer a *quantidade de pessoas* que trabalham em uma **empresa**, separando por faixa **etária**, **idade** e **sexo**.

Fiz o exemplo abaixo, mas até agora não consegui fazer funcionar, acusa erro no alias.

```
qr_consulta.Close;    
qr_consulta.SQL.Clear;    
qr_consulta.SQL.Add('Select COUNT(*) as total FROM tb_pessoas where ps_idade  >= 34 and ps_idade <= 38 AND em_id =:r AND ps_sexo = "Masculino"' );      
qr_consulta.Params.ParamByName('r').AsInteger := result ;      
qr_consulta.Open();
```

Editado ----
Pessoal a consulta acima esta funcionando normalmente, mas do jeito que esta ele esta calculando a idade direto (estava guardando a idade não a data de nascimento), alterei o campo para date no banco de dados e agora estou guardando a data de nascimento, preciso que traga a quantidade de pessoas separando pela empresa, idade com base na data de nascimento, compare a faixa de idade que defini e o sexo.Tentei a consulta abaixo mas não esta funcionando.

```
result := dbl_consulta.KeyValue;
  qr_consulta.Close;
  qr_consulta.SQL.Clear;
  qr_consulta.SQL.Add('Select COUNT(*) as total FROM tb_pessoas where (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.ps_idade, CURDATE()) as idade FROM tb_pessoas p) idade >= 29 and idade <= 33 AND em_id =:r AND ps_sexo = "Masculino"' );
```

As tabelas estão assim:

```
tb_pessoas

ps_id
ps_nome
ps_idade
ps_sexo
em_id

tb_empresas
em_id
em_nome
em_endereco
em_cnpj
em_telefone
```

Comment: Amigo, monta em esquema no http://sqlfiddle.com/ pra facilitar o entendimento e os testes da SELECT.

Comment: Defina como estão os dados e como deseja obtê-los, em todo caso pesquise por CASE , GROUP BY e DATETIME FUNCTIONS.

Comment: Quais são as faixas de idade que voce quer pegar?

Comment: Euler01, nesse exemplo quero as pessoas entre 29 a 33 anos

Comment: Emerson, eu não conhecia essa ferramenta sqlfiddle.com, estou dando uma olhada.

Comment: Motta, tentei com TIMESTAMPDIFF no exemplo que coloquei agora acima, mas também não esta indo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso você tem que somar a quantidade de pessoas agrupando por empresa e por sexo. Utilize esta query:

```
SELECT COUNT(tb_pessoas.ps_id) AS quantidade, tb_empresas.em_nome, tb_pessoas.ps_sexo
FROM tb_pessoas
INNER JOIN tb_empresas ON tb_empresas.em_id = tb_pessoas.em_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ps_idade, NOW()) BETWEEN 29 AND 33 
AND tb_pessoas.ps_sexo = "Masculino"
AND tb_empresas.em_nome =:r
ORDER BY tb_empresas.em_nome
```

Comment: Euler01, funcionou perfeitamente direto no banco de dados, era isso mesmo que preciso, a unica coisa que faltou e acho que esqueci de mencionar é que a consulta é iniciada quando o usuário escolhe a empresa em um combobox. Ex: escolhe a empresa google, ali vai ter que trazer quantos funcionarios do sexo masculino entre 29 a 33 anos que a empresa possui. Na consulta que montei eu passava o nome da empresa pela variável 'r' no qr_consulta.Params.ParamByName('r').AsInteger := result ; Nesta consulta que você me ajudou não imagino aonde poderia entrar essa variável trazendo o nome da empresa...

Comment: ... e também setar o sexo na consulta como Masculino

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver, segue abaixo a consulta que solucionou o meu problema, usei a consulta do Euler01 como base:

```
SELECT COUNT(tb_pessoas.ps_id) AS quantidade, tb_empresas.em_nome, tb_pessoas.ps_sexo
FROM tb_pessoas
INNER JOIN tb_empresas ON tb_empresas.em_id = tb_pessoas.em_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ps_idade, NOW())
BETWEEN 29 AND 33 AND tb_pessoas.ps_sexo = "Masculino"
ORDER BY tb_empresas.em_nome =:r
```

Pessoal muito obrigado a todos pelas ajudas, foram muito úteis para mim! Foi meu primeiro post, espero também poder contribuir com a comunidade com o pouco de conhecimento que tenho! Abraço!

Comment: Beleza, via agora os comentários. Boa sorte.

Comment: Euler01, pior que postei que funcionou mas ao escolher uma empresa diferente ele está trazendo os mesmos dados, não esta diferenciando as empresas. Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui pra tentar resolver ainda.

Comment: Estava errado porque voce estava colocando o filtro no ORDER BY e tem que ser no WHERE. Atualizei minha resposta com a query correta. Testa la

Comment: Euler01, show de bola, agora esta perfeito!! a unica coisa que precisei mudar na sua resposta foi no filtro tb_empresas.em_nome =:r eu coloquei tb_empresas.em_id =: r, pois no meu combobox estou capturando o id da tabela e o próprio campo associa com o nome. Mais uma vez muito obrigado! Agora sim o problema esta encerrado!! Abraço!